# Ability to remove drill through filter using slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, drillthrough, powerbi-filters

I need a slicer which will override the drill through filter or even disable it if possible.

I have a report where I am using a DAX measure to calculate SUM(Sales) for consumer segment in a card visual.

Here's the DAX measure.

```
SalesForConsumer =
CALCULATE(SUM(Orders[Sales]),Orders[Segment] = "Consumer")
```

[image]

After applying drill-through to the card, this is how drill-through page looks with page level filter on consumer which is correct.

[image]

I need the slicer in the drill-through page to show slicer options for other segments as well and not just consumers. Drill-through should filter the report as intended but I want the slicer to be selected for 'consumer' and still show the other slicer options.

Something like this:
[image]

Currently it is not possible without actually removing the drill through filter for visualizations pane.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2xvzjv3la7i5xvwm6ba89/Test-DB-for-Drill-through.pbix?dl=0&rlkey=zo1rdz6sw1kt8hnu4o90t3ato) is the PBIX file:

Please help.